# How can I set a binding to DocumentPageView.DocumentPaginator in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xps, xpsdocument

how binding DocumentPageView in WPF?
my code:

```
<DocumentPageView DocumentPaginator="{Binding Source}"></DocumentPageView>
```

Source is type of DocumentPaginator.
error is:

> Error  1   A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'DocumentPaginator' property of type 'DocumentPageView'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

please help me.
Tnx...

Answer (score 3):

Your error message says it all.  You can only apply a binding to a DependencyProperty.  DocumentPaginator is not a DependencyProperty of DocumentPageView, so you cannot bind to it.